# Where can I find data related to Availability of world energy resources?

Tags: data-request, energy

I am looking for data related to availability of world energy resources. I am collecting this data for a project which deals with creating Infographic.

Answer (score 1):

International Energy Agency (IEA) http://www.iea.org/
makes quite a bit of data available, including oil, gas and renewables.

Joint Organisations Data Initiative (JODI) (http://www.jodidata.org)
was created to gather and share data about oil and oil supplies. They make some interesting databases available online.

These two organizations are generally open, but you would need to dig around to determine the exact nature of their data licensing.

Wood Mackenzie (http://www.woodmac.com) has massive amounts of data covering oil and gas. But their data is definitely not 'open'.

Answer (score 1):

OpenEI (Energy Information) offers "Linked energy information on hundreds of topics crowdsourced from industry and government agencies":
http://en.openei.org/wiki/Main_Page

OpenEI works with a number of governments and institutions to serve up crowdsourced energy information; here's one example, their collaboration with NREL (National Renewable Energy Laboratory):
https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/electricity/openei-utility-rates/

Answer (score 0):

Another meta-resource would be the **[UN Energy](http://www.un-energy.org/tools)** tools page:

On that page are links to different UN resources related to energy, for example

- [Energy Technology Data Exchange World Energy Base (ETDEWEB)](https://www.etde.org/etdeweb/)
- [Measuring energy access](http://www.un-energy.org/measuring-energy-access)

---

and FAO (Food and Agriculture Organization of the UN) also has energy data (see [here](http://www.fao.org/energy/home/en/))

---

and the [WorldBank](http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/energy) has energy data available (see [here](https://data.worldbank.org/topic/energy-and-mining))

[image]