# Comprehensive open data on energy resource statistics?

Tags: data-request, energy, environment

I'm trying to find one or more open databases that contain comprehensive historical data about oil, coal, natural gas, solar, wind, biofuels, biomass, nuclear, wave, tidal, and hydro energy.

For each of these resource types, I'm looking for historical monthly or yearly time series data, globally and broken down by country, on consumption, capacity factor, real price (price paid at energy auctions), cost per kWh, cost of new plant production, number of existing plants, number of newly planned plants, number of newly cancelled plants, and (less importantly) public opinion data on each of these energy resource types, as well as any other data that is relevant to analyzing the relation between the growth of renewable energy and the decline of fossil fuels.

I've been able to find plenty of graphs depicting these trends, but what I need is raw data. Ideally, I would hope to find this data available via API, though any links to relevant up-to-date databases would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please check the resources here https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5523/1511 (duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have everything you ask for, but it certainly has consumption and price data broken down by fuel type: https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/browser/

Answer (score 0):

British Petroleum provides a lot of data through [quandl](https://www.quandl.com/data/BP-British-Petroleum).

If you are using Python, you definitely want to make use of the [quandl module](https://www.quandl.com/tools/python) to import the data into a pandas DataFrame.

Some of the relevant codes are:

- Oil production: `BP/OIL_PROD_XXX`
- Oil consumption: `BP/OIL_CONSUM_XXX`
- Oil Refinery Throughputs: `BP/OIL_REF_THR_XXX`

where `XXX` is the **ISO 3166 ALPHA-3** country code.

---

**UPDATE**

Seems that BP entry page at quandl had a wee bit of a hiccup, but while I update my answer, everything seems to be fine again.

Again, while quandl does offer so-called premium datasets too, all datasets that I mentioned are **available at no cost**!

If you prefer to download the data through your browser,here's a typical link for the [Oil Production in Canada](https://www.quandl.com/data/BP/OIL_PROD_CAN-Oil-Production-Canada).

Comment: as far as i know quandl is for profit, and their data is behind a paywall. that link to bp you provided shows nothing for quite awhile then throws a 500 error. from their home page, a quick search for me only showed premium datasets which are locked behind the paywall. all of this is not open data, so i'm voting to close this answer unless you can provide examples of this data as open data.